# this.set(charHere) in JAVA

Tags: java, constructor, char, set

I can't find anything in my text related to setting a char. I thought it was suppose to be a blank ' '

Could someone please lend me some advice? I have searched on here, google. my text, etc. I would just like to knock a little more of this lab out before I head to bed tonight. I know this is a very beginner question, but all my research online just brings back array char questions.

```
public class RateEstimator
{
    // instance variables
    private boolean smoker;
    private char gender;
    private int age;
    private boolean highRisk;
    private int numTickets;
    private String health;

    // constants

    /**
     * base rate for a 100K face value policy.
     */
    public static final double BASE_RATE = 45.0;

    /**
     *?????????????????ASK HOW TO CONSTRUCT BOOLEAN AND CHAR???????
     *First constructor for objects of class RateEstimator.
     */

    public RateEstimator()
    {
        // REPLACE these comments and return statement
        // with your coding of this constructor
        this.setSmoker(false);
        this.setGender(' ');
        this.setAge(0);
        this.setHighRisk(false);
        this.setNumTickets(0);
        this.setHealth("Good");

    }
```

Comment: Where are you setters? That is the correct syntax, but you're calling a lot of methods that don't exist in the code you showed.

Comment: Or since you're in the constructor, there's no use in going through setters. `this.gender = ' ';` will work just fine (and same for the others).

Comment: setting a `char`??? - `char ch = ' ';`// here char is blank

Comment: that's the problem, it's blank. it needs to be set to a default value, my choices are 'm' 'M' 'F' 'f', so I am unsure if 1. it matters what default value I choose, and 2, if so, which to choose. To clarify, and I am sorry for this, I am still learning how to ask these questions properly, we are correcting a life policy, and also a test policy, to these values will be tested, in the tester class.

Comment: I would prefer to have an overloaded constructor which omitted certain parameters, and in that case then assigned a default value to them.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, the portion of the coding assignment with which you are struggling is the implementation of a constructor for the `RateEstimator` class.  The following code is the vanilla-flavor constructor I would write for the class.

```
public RateEstimator(boolean smoker, char gender, int age, boolean highRisk,
    int numTickets, String health) {
    this.smoker = smoker;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.highRisk = highRisk;
    this.numTickets = numTickets;
    this.health = health;
}
```

Further explanation:

The `this` operator refers to the instance of the `RateEstimator` object which is being constructed.  So `this.age = age` means assign the constructor parameter `age` to the variable contained within the instance of the `RateEstimator` class.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the default constructor. I am only allowed to add code under the // comments areas. I keep getting error, cannot find symbol method setGender(char). My boolean this.setSmoker is able to compile, so why does this char cause an error?

Comment: I think your original question is too vague.  So what are you expected to add to the constructor then?

Comment: I just updated my first response to you, I am setting these objects, smoker, gender etc... on my first constructor, then in the next constructor I will call them for example this.Gender = inGender. I hope that helps, sorry, I am still learning, and struggling with some basics.

Comment: @jforrest1980 There is no method named `setGender(char c)`, so of course it will be an error if you try to call a non-existing method. You don't need to use setters in the constructor either.